# Google Sheet - Dealing with unusual date format with MAXIFS function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I'm trying to filter data based on email address matching and date matching.
My issue is the dates come in an unusual format (e.g: 2023-01-10 01:21:45 UTC).

I've been using a helper column instead to make the formula lighter. However, for automation purposes it would be much easier to have the true date format integrated to the formula.

Below is the formula I'm currently using in A2. My goal is to remove column D from formula and use only column C instead. I was trying to replace `'Sample Data for LOOKUP'!D:D` by `=ARRAYFORMULA(DATEVALUE(left(C2:C14,10)))` but it does not work.

```
=filter('Sample Data for LOOKUP'!E:E,'Sample Data for LOOKUP'!D:D=MAXIFS('Sample Data for LOOKUP'!D:D,'Sample Data for LOOKUP'!B:B,"<>",ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE('Sample Data for LOOKUP'!A:A,"(.+@)",)),REGEXREPLACE(B2,"(.+@)",)),(REGEXREPLACE(B2,"(.+@)",)=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE('Sample Data for LOOKUP'!A:A,"(.+@)",))),('Sample Data for LOOKUP'!B:B<>""))
```

Here is a sample file to make it easier to understand my issue:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18R-4m682SeHNBgnzJCM1l0Fef13D5vYG3gmeWDveSYQ/edit#gid=1722273432

Comment: Your end goal remains unclear. Please clarify what you are trying to do. Make sure you are not asking an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying in cell A2 to cut column D in 'Sample Data for LOOKUP' tab. I would like to use column C instead with the unusual date format.

To get the latest `Status` for each email address domain listed in column `B2:B`, preferring statuses where column `Lookup!B2:B` is not blank, use `vlookup()` and `sort()`, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  iferror( 
    vlookup( 
      regexextract(B2:B, "@(.+)"), 
      sort( 
        { regexextract(Lookup!A2:A, "@(.+)"), Lookup!E2:E }, 
        sign(len(trim(Lookup!B2:B))), false, 
        Lookup!C2:C, false 
      ), 
      2, 
      false 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

See your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18R-4m682SeHNBgnzJCM1l0Fef13D5vYG3gmeWDveSYQ/edit#gid=546411810).

Comment: Thank you the formula works! May I just know if you could add one criteria to the formula: if Lookup!B:B is not empty (in my initial formula -> Lookup!B:B<>"" I'm not used to this kinda formula structure so I did not succeed to add it to your formula.

Comment: Edited the answer per your new requirements. Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741).

Comment: thanks a lot, appreciate the effort. have a good day :)